# Mysql inserting values

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am storing an Object into my database, and I think I am making some stupid mistake which I don't see. I attached some code to understand my problem:

**MyObject.java** object which I want to store in the database

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_object")
public class MyObject {
    private String idName;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, length = 50,nullable=false)
    public String getIdName() {
        return idName;
    }
    public void setIdName(String idName) {
        this.idName = idName;
        this.id = idName.hashCode();
    }
```

**TestToStoreObject.java**

```
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
                
                obj.setIdName("id");
//More set ...
                save(obj);
```

Function to store the Object into the database

```
protected void save(MyObject obj) throws DataAccessLayerException {
        try{
            getHibernateTemplate().save(obj);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            handleException(e);
        }
    }
```

This is a general function which is working with other datatypes. So where I guess the problem is, is in configuration files. The exception is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
   could not insert: [path.MyObject]; SQL [insert into object (id) values (?)];
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
   could not insert: [path.MyObject]
```

Here more configuration files:
**HibernatePlatform.cfg.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
            "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <mapping class="path.User" />
            <mapping class="path.MyObject" />
```

Comment: Do you have a table `object` with column `id` and no other not-null constraints? What is the type of column `id`?

Comment: what's the `id` column? Try to insert that record through mysql console

Comment: It a String. Check Object.java   @Column(name = "id", unique = true, length = 50,nullable=false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had another class with the same name in another package, and it was messing. A piece of advise for the future: chach this small things!!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess - you've defined a class named `Object` and there's a good chance, that you have name clashes between your class `Object` and the java class `java.lang.Object`. It's possible, that you try to store an `java.lang.Object` accidently.

For a quick test: refactor your class to `MyObject` (using eclipse, netbeans, ...). If some types named `Object` are *not* changed after refactoring, then my guess could be right.

Comment: Actually Object is not the name of my object, I just wrote a general name. Anyway I will edit my question. Thanks

Comment: @mujer esponja - ... better choose a better general name next time :(